# Completeness of a finite dimensional vector space under the metric induced by a norm

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studying linear algebra from "Linear algebra done right" by Sheldon Axler, and I found an exercise asking me to prove that any normed, finite dimensional vector space over the field of the real or complex numbers is a complete metric space with respect to the metric induced by the norm. I was not able to do any progress on this, so I searched online and I only found answers using the equivalence of 2 norms on a finite dimensional vector space, something that it's never been mentioned in the book so far, so I'm here asking if anyone could provide a proof that doesn't use this fact, thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I can see Axler does not consider general normed vector spaces, only inner-product spaces. And I cannot find any mention of complete metric spaces in Axler. Is this exercise in Axler?

Comment: Axler doesn't treat normed vector space in depth, but there are a couple of exercise about them. Also this is the 29-th exercise in section 6.A of Axler's Linear algebra done right third edition

Comment: OK, thanks. I think Axler in this exercise is only dealing with inner product spaces rather than more general normed spaces, which he doesn't define. This explains why he doesn't discuss equivalent norms.

Comment: I wasn't sure of this too, In the exercise text it's not specified, It's only said that there is a norm on this vector space so I assumed it was a normed space and not necessarily an inner product space. I'm not sure how much different the situation is from my question perspective

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exercise 29 in Section 6.A of Linear Algebra Done Right starts by defining a metric $d$ on the inner product space $V$ by $$d(u, v) = \|u-v\|.$$

In the statement of this exercise, $V$ is indeed an inner product space because 11 pages earlier there is a box stating "for the rest of this chapter, $V$ denotes an inner product space". Then norms throughout the chapter refer to the norm induced by the inner product. Thus to produce a solution to this exercise, it is not necessary to use the result that all norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent. A key tool to use in the solution is the result that every finite-dimensional inner product space has an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Thanks, I will try doing it myself, just I don't understand why this exercise is given here where the proof of the fact that every finite dimensional inner product space has an orthonormal basis lies in the next section

Comment: Evan, you make a good point here. I will move this exercise to Section 6.B in the next edition of Linear Algebra Done Right.